# REST Assured: How to find element using nested property in JSON and validate other properties

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest-assured, hamcrest, mockmvc

I have limited experience with rest assured. We have a number of tests that I can usually find examples within, or failing that google, but I am stuck when trying to match on a nested property for an element in an anonymous array, and verify properties up across and down (cousins?).

Example JSON:

```
[  
   {  
      "id":1,
      "type":{  
         "typeId":3,
         "name":"LPM"
      },
      "status":{  
         "id":1,
         "price":1.20,
         "source":172,
         "valid":0
      }
   },
   {  
      "id":2,
      "type":{  
         "typeId":2,
         "name":"ST"
      },
      "status":{  
         "id":10,
         "price":1.20,
         "source":172,
         "valid":0
      }
   }
]
```

I'm using rest assured, and I want to find the element in the list that has `type.name` equal to LPM, and then validate `status.price`, `status.source`, and `status.id` of only that element.

When I initially started validating the responses, it was only possible for one item to be in the array, so I was using:

```
response.then()
        .assertThat()
        .body("size", greaterThan(0))
        .body("[0].type.name", equalToIgnoringCase("LPM"))
        .body("[0].status.id", equalTo(statusId))
        .body("[0].status.source", equalTo(sourceId))
        .body("[0].status.price", equalTo(price));
```

However this is no longer assured to work, as there may be more than one element in the array, and the order is not guaranteed.

I have modified my body checks to be:

```
response.then()
        .assertThat()
        .body("size", greaterThan(0))
        .body("type.name", hasItem("LPM"))
        .body("status.id", hasItem(statusId))
        .body("status.source", hasItem(sourceId))
        .body("status.price", hasItem(price));
```

This is enough to get the test to pass, but this introduces the risk that the `status.id`, `status.source`, and `status.price` of the element with `type.name` LPM could be incorrect, but this would not be detected as they would be matched against the element with `type.name` ST.

So I want to be able to find the element which has LPM as it's `type.name`, of which I can guarantee there to be only one, and then for `status.id`, `status.source`, and `status.price`, check that element only, i.e. **NOT** the ST element.

I tried to modify my body matcher to find the elements with the `type.name` that I need, but I can't get this to work, as I can't figure out how to go back up the tree, across and down, to check other attributes in the same element:

```
response.then()
        .assertThat()
        .body("size", greaterThan(0))
        .body("$.findAll (it.type.name = LPM}.status.id ", hasItem(statusId))
        .body("$.findAll (it.type.name = LPM}.status.source", hasItem(sourceId))
        .body("$.findAll (it.type.name = LPM}.status.price", hasItem(price));
```

Also even if this worked, it would search the tree 3 times when really once would have done.

My middle matches have this test passing for now but I want to get this right. I'm aware I could get the elements into a `List` and work it out from there, but for consistency with the rest of our examples I'd rather not, though I currently can't see another option.

I have tried to find examples of what I'm trying to do in documentation, multiple rest assured tutorials and examples but I haven't, so there is always the possibility that this isn't actually possible. If not I'm happy to educate don the theory behind it.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Do you insist on doing this only witj REST Assured?

Comment: @GrzegorzGórkiewicz yes, I do not want to introduce another testing framework. If I can't do it the way I want, then I'll deserialize the json into a List and iterate over it.

Comment: I didn't mean another **testing** framework. I wanted to use for example Google's GSON to instantiate a list of JSONObjects and then assert with Hamcrest that this list contains an element with the wanted property.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Here's one way to do it:

```
...
then().
        root("find {it.type.name == '%s'}.status").
        body("id", withArgs("LPM"), is(1)).
        body("price", withArgs("LPM"), is(1.20f)).
        body("source", withArgs("LPM"), is(172)).
        body("id", withArgs("ST"), is(10));
```

(you can obviously extract `withArgs` to a variable as well to avoid repetition).

`find` is Groovy's way of finding the first element matching the predicate (`{it.type.name == '%s'}`), `findAll` will always return a list.

`root` instructs REST Assured to use a "root path" that is used in subsequent expectations (see [docs](https://github.com/rest-assured/rest-assured/wiki/Usage#root-path)).

Comment: Thanks! This worked perfectly. This is a very elegant solution; much neater than having to deserialise the JSON and iterate.